# CX_ORACLE Connect via a Password file

Tags: python-2.7, cx-oracle

Is it possible to have a reference file/document that houses a username & password when using a TNS with CX_Oracle?

The main reason for this is added security instead of saving the User ID (USER123) & Password (P455w0rd) into a python script.

The example below logs onto a Database & return the DB Version. Does anyone have an ideas on how to reference out the Username & Password?

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('USER123','P455w0rd','ORPM2')#TNSNAME.ORA 
print con.version
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options that I am aware of:

1) Use a secure password store (aka wallet)

2) Use operating system authentication

3) Use network authentication (e.g. Kerberos)

All of these are explained on the following page:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authentication.htm#DBSEG99815

The first one is probably closest to what you have in mind but the others are also options that will solve the problem for you.